# A javascript number type question

Tags: javascript

Why 1.toFixed(2) get syntax error while

```
var a = 1;
a.toFixed(2)
```

won't.

Moreover, why does 1.1.toFixed(2) run alright?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1.` starts a float so `1.toFixed()` is incorrect syntax. You could use `(1).toFixed()` though.

`1.1.toFixed()` works fine because after `1.1` you are already in a float so the parser won't take `.` as the beginning of a float but as an object method call.